# Can we use django builtin function of password reset for all users?(not for admin)

Tags: django, passwords, reset

I am new to Django and I have started developing a website, where I provide the functionality of user login, logout and password reset. But I am not able to use Django default password reset as I am only getting email verification link to the superuser only. I need the password resetting for all users rather than superuser.

Comment: Does each user have an e-mail address? The `createsuperuser` command prompts for it but other times Django itself does not. Also how are you sending the messages? The recipient server could be rejecting them because they are not signed.